# How do we create a cronExpression using Java code

Tags: jakarta-ee

for example if i want to convert 2011-03-27T11:15:05 this date to a valid cron expression how would i do that

Comment: Thats right Harry how do i create it using Java Code

Comment: @Harry: I understood that but how do we create it using the java code, bcoz i'm new to Java

Comment: @Harry: Also we have Quartz-Scheduler and in that we have CronExpression class,how do we convert the above expression using the Quartz CronExpression java file

Answer (score 0):

To build a cron expression here is the sequence:

1. Seconds
2. Minutes
3. Hours
4. Day of month
5. Month
6. Day of week
7. Year[optional]

So if you look at the expression `05 15 11 27 03 ? 11` It says fire on 27 march 2011 at 11:15:05.

In java you easily can get this information from date. So now I think you will be bale to create a cron expression.

Hope this helps.

Reference:- [cron_expressions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14003_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm)

---

**Edit:-**

Here is an example:-

```
SchedulerFactory sf=new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched=sf.getScheduler();
sched.start();

JobDetail jd=new JobDetail("myjob",Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP,CronTestHelper.class);       
CronTrigger tr=new CronTrigger("my",Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP,"05 15 11 27 03 ? 11");

sched.scheduleJob(jd, tr);
```